# Grep one liner to remove blocks of random text

Tags: text-processing, grep

Using a script to backup some Cisco routers and compare startup and running configs. My output is tarnished by some ssl certificates it returns - I wish to remove them.

Given:

```
*********  ERROR running diff on: AVE-1941-LAN config files Code: 0 ***************
 certificate self-signed 01                   |  certificate self-signed 01 nvram:IOS-Self-Sig#1.cer
  30820253 308201BC A0030201 02020101 300D0609 2A864886 F70D0 <
  31312F30 2D060355 04031326 494F532D 53656C66 2D536967 6E656 <
  69666963 6174652D 33393336 35313332 3733301E 170D3131 31323 <
  33355A17 0D323030 31303130 30303030 305A3031 312F302D 06035 <
  4F532D53 656C662D 5369676E 65642D43 65727469 66696361 74652 <
  31333237 3330819F 300D0609 2A864886 F70D0101 01050003 818D0 <
  81008EE9 17E0DDA9 B9ACAEEE 788267CD 1A6E7B99 15A1797E C1AFE <
  97F5E44A 7CA1E814 E329EEC3 1C6229CD 5C78C9FB F5107E23 FE386 <
  E7FA1849 BBA4884C 6001925E 6B2D2987 415AB429 ECDFCF87 E708D <
  C22F137C E5778EC0 E8F6A0FB 30A2EEF7 AB2E5E77 53F2D83B B7497 <
  8A5F0203 010001A3 7B307930 0F060355 1D130101 FF040530 03010 <
  551D1104 1F301D82 1B424553 2D313934 312D4176 652E796F 75726 <
  2E636F6D 301F0603 551D2304 18301680 14895C79 C998FF5B 08E1A <
  F3866724 C4301D06 03551D0E 04160414 895C79C9 98FF5B08 E1A23 <
  866724C4 300D0609 2A864886 F70D0101 04050003 81810002 DE0D3 <
  4708834D C2267F49 86A62B31 A505D0F9 79BBC295 1C8DB831 39467 <
  4A1F9149 DDB2ACDE CEE3DCB4 9CDAD85F 457D00BF BFBA3058 52188 <
  FD497E36 93C06D1D C35012B6 A61A35FC 88681759 C51F6C0A A79A9 <
  DB5391E9 49575BD5 50B6319E 065C2C99 4D9AB450 9D22D8         <
    quit
```

I would like to end up with;

```
*********  ERROR running diff on: AVE-1941-LAN config files Code: 0 ***************
 certificate self-signed 01                   |  certificate self-signed 01 nvram:IOS-Self-Sig#1.cer
        quit
```

Is this possible with a grep one liner with perhaps regex?

Answer (score 4):

Provided that the output is limited to what you have there, just getting rid of those unwanted lines would be:

```
grep -v '[0-9A-F]\{5\} <$'
```

To have the newlines removed as well, I'd probably pipe it into another `grep` command, since it's easy to read that way:

```
grep -v '[0-9A-F\{5\} <$' | grep -v '^$'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always use PERL or GAWK:

```
$ perl -ne 'print unless /<\s*$/' input_file
```

or

```
$ gawk '$NF!~/</'
```

Both scriptlets will print all lines that do NOT end with "<".

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`:

```
sed '/<\s*$/,/^\s*$/d'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
grep -v '^[0-9A-F]\{8\}'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it does not even apear to touch it.http://pastebin.com/HmTsVuH2

Comment: Try `grep -v '^[[:space:]]*[0-9A-F]\{8\}.*[[:space:]]<$`. It will remove all lines that that begin with at least 8 hex characters and end with < character.